# Can I set the Visual Studio compiler to conform to a specific version of c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

Can I set the Visual Studio compiler to conform to a specific version of c++ (e.g. C++03 or C++11)?  If so, how?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. Pretty much the only flag for controlling the language is `/Za` (don't use Microsoft extensions), and that's so broken that the MS STL isn't even tested with it, and parts might not compile - not to mention the Windows SDK headers.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 obviously can not be set to C++11 compatibility. (less obviously 2012 can't be either...)

As for C++03 it is fairly compatible, you can find the short list of differences in msdn. Also the options to turn off extensions, though that switch has no practical use.